# Using Knockout push in a function returns an error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

In this example, I'm using knockout with require.js.

Outside Main.roll(), Main.result.push works as expected.  Inside the function, it throw an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined.

I can still access Main.result() in the function. I can set values to it, but I can't use .push for some reason.

```
define(['knockout', 'd20'], function(ko, d20) {

  return function main() {
    var Main = this;

    Main.result = ko.observableArray('');

    Main.result.push( d20.roll('2d8+2') ); // works

    Main.roll = function() {

      Main.result('');

      Main.result.push( d20.roll('2d8+2') );  // no workie
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: If you remove the `Main.result('')` line inside that function, does it change anything?

Comment: Ya, but I had to reset the array. This was the wrong syntax.  The answer below got it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect. You are dealing with an array so you can't set it to empty string. Following are the two ways for initializing the array:

Either this :

```
Main.result = ko.observableArray([]);
```

or this :

```
Main.result = ko.observableArray();
```

However, if you wish to reset it to empty array use the code snippet below:

```
Main.result([]);
```